# How to put a my own proxy between any client and any server (via a web page)

Tags: java, web, proxy

what I want to do is to build a web application(proxy) that user use to request the webpage he want and 
my application forward the request to the main server, 
modify HTML code,
send to the client the modified one.

The question now is
How to keep my application between the client and main serevr
(for example when the user click any link inside the modified page-
ajax request - submit forms - and so on)

in another words
How to grantee that any request (after the first URL request) from the client sent to my proxy and any response come first to my proxy

Answer (score 0):

The question is: Why do you need a proxy? Why do you want to build it - why not use already existing one like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) ?

EDIT: sorry, I didn't read your whole post correctly. You can start with:
http://www.jtmelton.com/2007/11/27/a-simple-multi-threaded-java-http-proxy-server/

Answer (score 0):

If the user is willing to, or can be forced<sup>1</sup> to configure his clients (e.g. web browser) to use a web proxy, then your problem is already solved.    Another way to do this (assuming that the user is cooperative) is to get them to install a trusted browser plugin that dynamically routes *selected* URLs through your proxy.  But you can't do this using an untrusted webapp: the Browser sandbox won't (shouldn't) let you.

Doing it without the user's knowledge and consent requires some kind of interference at the network level.  For example, a "smart" switch could recognizes TCP/IP packets on port 80 and deliberately route them to your proxy instead of the IP address that the client's browser specifies.  This kind of thing is known as "deep packet inspection".  It would be very difficult to implement yourself, and it requires significant compute power in your network switch if you are going to achieve high network rates through the switch.

The second problem is that making meaningful on-the-fly modifications to arbitrary HTML + Javascript responses is a really difficult problem.

The final problem is that this is only going to work with HTTP.  HTTPS protects against "man in the middle" attacks ... such as this ... that monitor or interfere with the requests and responses.  The best you could hope to do would be to capture the encrypted traffic between the client and the server.

---

<sup>1 - The normal way to force a user to do this is to implement a firewall that blocks all outgoing HTTP connections *apart* from those made via your proxy.</sup>

---

**UPDATE**

> The problem now what should I change in the html code to enforce client to request any thing from my app --- for example for link href attribute may be www.aaaa.com?url=www.google.com but for ajax and form what I should do?

Like I said, it is a difficult task.  You have to deal with the following problems:

- Finding and updating absolute URLs in the HTML.  (Not hard)
- Finding and dealing with the base URL (if any).  (Not hard)
- Dealing with the URLs that you don't want to change; e.g. links to CSS, javascript (maybe), etc.  (Harder ...)
- Dealing with HTML that is syntactically invalid ... but not to the extent that the browser can't cope.  (Hard)
- Dealing with cross-site issues.  (Uncertain ...)
- Dealing with URLs in requests being made by javascript embedded in / called from the page.  This is extremely difficult, given the myriad ways that javascript could assemble the URL.
- Dealing with HTTPS.  (Impossible to do securely; i.e. without the user not trusting the proxy to see private info such as passwords, credit card numbers, etc that are normally sent securely.)
- and so on.

Comment: thanks Stephen C for your reply. I think there are some confusion. Steps I do for my project (webpage content adaptation for mobiles). 1- User go to my url say www.aaaa.com (this page has a field for url to enter) 2- user write the page url he want 3- my application request this page, modify , send to client ------ I do this .The problem now what should I change in the html code to enforce client to request any thing from my app --- for example for link href attribute may be www.aaaa.com?url=www.google.com but for ajax and form what I should do?